# Django поведение CreateView класса в зависимости от того какое поле подели заполнено

Tags: python, django, django-view

Допустим есть модель
**models.py**:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    input_int = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    input_str = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

**form.py**:

```
class UserDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = '__all__'
```

Как сделать ветвление в CreateView классе в зависимости от того, какое поле модели заполнено.

Например
**views.py**:

```
class UserDataView(generic.CreateView):
    model = UserData
    form_class = UserDataForm
    
    # !далее псевдокод который не понимаю как реализовать! 
    if input_int:
        #create object with some int value and str==null
    elif input_str:
        #create object with some str value and int==null
```

как правильно написать код в CreateView классе в зависимости от того какое поле ввел пользователь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализовать этот функционал в методе `form_valid` он будет вызываться если пользователь ввел данные формы корректно.

```
class UserDataView(generic.CreateView):
    model = UserData
    form_class = UserDataForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.cleaned_data.get('input_int'):
            # create object with some int value and str==null
        elif form.cleaned_data.get('input_str'):
            # create object with some str value and int==null
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как далее при выполнении первого условия выполнить "стандартное" создание объекта? Так: `super(UserDataView, self).form_valid(form)`  ?